# Rename multiple files using sed command after removing the string after the last underscore

Tags: filenames, rename

I have a set of files in a directory as shown below and I want to remove the string after the occurrence of the last underscore from it. The string may be different each time. It will be good if it can be done with `sed`.

Input files:

```
com_101_00000_0001_a234.txt
com_101_retail_00000_0002_g345.ctl
com_101_lines_003_0002_1134.txt
```

Resulting file names:

```
com_101_00000_0001.txt
com_101_retail_00000_0002.ctl
com_101_lines_00003_0002.txt
```

Comment: Why `sed`? Sed doesn't deal with files, it only deals with text. More importantly, what operating system are you using? Is it a Linux variant? Unix? MacOS? BSD? Something else?

Comment: Would there ever be a conflict? With an existing file named, say, `com_101_00000_0001.txt` before you start the renaming process? What should happen in that case, if so?

Comment: I tried with sed to Edit the file name ..But couldn't get the .Txt or .ctl part appeneded.that's why i thought it will be easy to follow up.but it's ok whichever command appropriate in this scenario can use. Unix variant system am using.

Comment: _What_ Unix variant system? There are significant differences in the way the various default tools behave on different systems. Please [edit] your question and give us the actual operating system you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your system has the perl `rename`, you can do:

```
rename -n 's/_[^_]+?\././' *
```

If your files could end up with the same name, to avoid overwriting them, use `-i`:

```
rename -in 's/_[^_]+?\././' *
```

If that does what you expect, remove the `-n` to actually rename the files.

If you really insist on shoehorning `sed` into this, you could do something needlessly complicated like this:

```
for f in *_*.*; do
    new=$(printf "%s\n" "$f" | sed 's/\(.*\)_[^_]*\(\.[^_]*\)$/\1\2/')
    echo mv "$f" "$new"
done
```

Alternatively, without `sed`, the saner:

```
for f in *_*.*; do echo mv "$f" "${f%_*}.${f##*.}" ; done
```

For both of the last examples, if they do what you expect, remove the `echo` to actually rename the files.

Comment: Thank you for the reply @terdon. But system doesn't have perl,not able to use rename.

Comment: @Vinay well, that's precisely why I asked you (two times) to tell me what operating system you are using! And I give 3 solutions in my answer, do none of them work?

Comment: @Vinay I have given three options. And you _still_ haven't answered the simple question that will tell me what tools you can use. So I ask again. What operating system are you using?

Comment: The system we are keeping these files maintained by seperate team ,we have just access to a few folders from where we move this to our servers .If I am correct it's Linux /Unix installed machine .

Comment: ..Definitely i will check the solutions shared ,to see which one works fine for me

Comment: @jeff duplicate or same file names won't be transferred in an ideal scenario

Comment: @Vinay Linux is not Unix, there is no such thing as "Linux /Unix" machine. If you have access to the machine, run the command `uname -a` and tell us what ir returns.

Comment: Sure ,will update by tomorrow morning since I don't have system access this time

Comment: last 2 solutions worked with the sed and the other one.great thanks .Can you please explain how the command works ,the reg expression part especially