# shell script /unix commands for text file content editing

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed, grep

I want to edit the file contents in the 2nd line and 2nd column ,which is a file name from that I want to remove the part after the last underscore and before the file extension .

The contents of the file looks like below
Input file contents

```
No|filename|count
01 |com_101_00000_0001_a234.txt|100
```

expected output file content

```
No|filename|count  
01 |com_101_00000_0001.txt|100
```

The number of underscores may vary depending upon the file names present inside the .ctl files.
Also there are multiple files in a folder likes this ,i want to change the contents for all .ctl files in the 2nd line similarly.

```
Operating system details Linux  2.6.32 -696.30.1.e16
GNU/linux
```

I tried with the below solution
cat com_101_00000_0001.ctl | sed 's/(.*)_[^_]*(.[^_]*)$/\1\2/'

This edited the file contents but shows the contents in the putty console itself ,what i want is to modify the original files in a particular path in server

Please tell where it went wrong

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: I tried this ,with the help of the forum and google 
i am a starter in unix but this doenst work it seems

Comment: Please add this information to your question and tell us what went wrong.

Comment: its added ,hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

This is the third time now you ask the nearly same question ( [Qu.1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/486392/rename-multiple-files-using-sed-command-after-removing-the-string-after-the-last), [Qu.2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486570/303610), and this one ) - how about collecting the answers given and see how far you get?

Did you try [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/486570/303610)? Please read about redirection if you want the result captured in a file.

Comment: Qu 2 and Qu3 are same as u said .Both deals with the file content editing,since i earlier wrongly described the requirement i asked as a fresh question(i'm new to the forum) . Qu 1 is regarding renaming the files. Qu3 now asked as an extension to that .hope it will be helpful for other beginners like me